# What does the ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that in $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$ we have $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and my instinct would be to say that any element in the ring has the form $a_0+a_1x+a_2y+a_3z+a_4x^2+a_5y^2+a_6z^2$. Is that correct or could we lose the squared terms because of the above relation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid your instinct isn't quite right - for example, $x^3$ is an element in your ring, which isn't of the form you described above.

The relation really says that you're allowed to convert $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ into $1$, so you can e.g. always get rid of the $x^2$ term of any polynomial, *or* the $y^2$ term, *or* the $z^2$ term, *or* the constant term (which is perhaps the most "symmetrical" way of putting it into a standard form).

Another answer, from algebraic geometry, is that it's exactly the ring of polynomials in $\mathbb R[x,y,z]$, with two considered the same if they happen to define the same function on the unit sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. Equivalently, it's the ring of functions from the unit sphere to $\mathbb R$ that can be expressed by a polynomial.

However, neither of these are particularly satisfying answers to the question! Unfortunately the answer is that on some level you just have to deal with the ring as it is, there isn't a significantly simpler ring that it is isomorphic to (as far as I can see).

Comment: "Equivalently, it's the ring of functions from the unit sphere to $\mathbb R$ that can be expressed by a polynomial." — Isn't that exactly the set of spherical harmonics?

Comment: I confess ignorance: would you consider e.g. $x^2 + y^2 + z^2+x$ to be the same as $1+x$, as spherical harmonics? If so, then you're probably right. If not, then no, because we're considering the polynomials merely as functions here.

Comment: Spherical harmonics are only defined on the unit sphere. They are not normally written as polynomials of $x$, $y$ and $z$, but if you write those in spherical coordinates, you get exactly the usual formulas for spherical harmonics. This is similar to how on the unit circle, $x$ translates to $\cos\phi$ and $y$ translates to $\sin\phi$, and then polynomials translate to functions involving multiples of angles, e.g. $x^2-y^2$ gives $\cos(2\phi)$. Of course $x^2+y^2$ translates to $\sin^2 \phi+\cos^2\phi$ which just is $1$. And of course the analogue thing happens in spherical harmonics.

Comment: Hm, I don't know. I would want to convince myself that there aren't any more relations satisfied by $\sin \phi \sin \theta$, $\cos \phi \sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ than the fact that they commute and $x^2+ y^2 +z^2 = 1$, but it is certainly plausible that you're correct.

Comment: @JoshHunt There aren't more relations, because they parametrize the whole unit sphere.